# How to display 2 records per row in XSLT (need count of records)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, xslt

I have a list named "Links". I want to display them in following format:

```
<tr>
    <td>Link1</td>
    <td>Link2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Link3</td>
    <td>Link4</td>
</tr>
```

So basically I want to display 2 records per row instead of the regular one. This requires that I calculate mod of current records being displayed. But I don't know how to get record number while looping records. In PHP I would normally do like this:

```
$i = 0;

while (looping through records)
{
    $i++;
    <calculate MOD of current row here>
}
```

But how do I do the same in XSL in SharePoint?

**EDIT**
I have hit a snag. This is what my code looks like but I am getting error.
Basically it is not accepting only "tr" and it also expects closing "/tr" but if I write that in first WHEN condition then my logic won't work.
So any other logic to make it work?

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <tr> (this is my error line)
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

<td>rest of my code will come here</td>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        </tr>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it. This is how you do it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position() mod 2">
```

Comment: Please check my edit above which I wrote after this answer.